# Form was not submitted with checkbox array

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

Although the following function has a little problem. But I can not find. Every time either checkbox is checked or not but form was not submitted!!

```
<input type="checkbox" name="chk_user[]" value="1" class="chk_delete" id="1"  />
<input type="checkbox" name="chk_user[]" value="2" class="chk_delete" id="2"  />
<input type="checkbox" name="chk_user[]" value="3" class="chk_delete" id="3"  />
<input type="checkbox" name="chk_user[]" value="4" class="chk_delete" id="4"  />
<script>
    $("form").submit(function() {
        $('.chk_delete').each(function(){
            if($(this).is(':checked')){            
                return true;

            }
        });
        alert("No entry was selected!");
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

Can anybody locate the problem?

The following is working, but I don't understand why. Any good logic?

```
$("form").submit(function(e) { 
    if(!$('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length) { 
        e.preventDefault(); 
        alert("No entry was selected!"); } 
     return true; });
```

Comment: Why is your form not wrapped in a `<form>` tag?

Comment: Please show the full HTML so we can see the structure of the form.

Comment: also script not in a script tag... I think we're missing something

Comment: Actually I did not mention the HTML because HTML and Scripts everything was okay. Anyway I find the solution although I don't know why the above jquery function was not working. But following is working....

$("form").submit(function(e) {
    if(!$('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length) {        
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("No entry was selected!");
    }
    return true;
});

Comment: Not sure if there is any problem in your html structure, but name="..." in the input tags matters when submitting through a form. You are using the same name for all of them, and it would probably cause an error

Comment: @IqbalHossain Great, it should be posted as an answer. If you can't, then I can do it for you.

Comment: @Fred, Yes I can not due to I have not enough permission. You can do it please...

Comment: @IqbalHossain Done. Cheers (just click on the accept as answer).

Comment: @IqbalHossain Basically, the logic behind this is, if `(!<= does not-negates)` `if(!$('input[type=checkbox]:checked')` is not checked, prevent from being submitted.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a whirl:

```
$("form").submit(function(e) {
  if(!$('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length) {
    e.preventDefault();

   alert("No entry was selected!"); }
return true; });
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `return true` into the `each` loop. Using return in the each loop just mean if the loop continue (on `true`) or if it stop (on `false`).

That beign said, you script will alway roll hover a `return false`, preventing the form from submiting.

**What you could do**

If you want to keep the loop, save if it's true or false in a var!

```
var isChecked = false;
$('.chk_delete').each(function(){
    isChecked = $(this).is(':checked')    
    return !isChecked;
});
return isChecked;
```

**OR**

Use your working script, I don't see what's wrong with it

```
$("form").submit(function(e) { 
    if(!$('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length) { 
        e.preventDefault(); 
        alert("No entry was selected!");
    } 
    return true;
});
```

`$('input[type=checkbox]:checked')` select every checked box. So `$('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length` take the length. Having `!` is the same thing as `!=`.

Finally, `!$('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length` is a shotcut for `$('input[type=checkbox]:checked') != 0`. If true, it `.preventDefault()` wich prevent the form of submiting.